# Another way of saying "in the form of..."

Tags: phrase-requests

"This dissertation is in the form of a literature review..." - PLEASE, tell me another way to say this!

Comment: "This literature review is actually a dissertation in disguise."

Answer (score 1):

This dissertation is a review of the literature...

Active voice!

Answer (score 0):

> This dissertation is presented as a literature review...
>
> This dissertation presents like a literature review...
>
> This dissertation takes the form of a literature review...